# Why the method call in end to copy constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy

I don't understand why in last line **return *newP;** the method enter to copy constructor this make memory leak, because I can't free the new `Poly` created from copy constructor?

```
const Poly Poly::operator * (const Poly &p1) const {
Poly* newP= new Poly;
delete newP->headList->mono;
newP->headList->mono=NULL;
delete newP->headList;
newP->headList=NULL;
newP->SetCount(0);
//two pointer to run on the list

Node* tmp,* tmp2;
tmp= this->headList;
tmp2=p1.headList;
Mono* mono= new Mono;
int n,d,p;
while (tmp != NULL)
{
    while (tmp2!=NULL)
    {
        *mono=(*tmp->mono)*(*tmp2->mono);
        n=mono->GetiNom();
        d=mono->GetiDenom();
        p=mono->GetPower();
        newP->Insert(n,d,p);
        tmp2=tmp2->next;
    }   
    tmp=tmp->next;
    tmp2=p1.headList;
}
delete mono;
return *newP;
}
```

Comment: Because you are returning a `const Poly` object. It is copied from `*newP`... You, probably, want to return a pointer to `Poly` which is just `newP` (you need to change the return type too and make sure caller knows that they have to `delete` it later).

Comment: With no disrespect, I don't understand why this question gets an upvote instead of being voted to be closed...

Answer (score 0):

You can return a reference by using `*this`, this is very useful for [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) for example. It does not leak memory, if the object is deleted somewhere else.

Well, since you edited your code, yes, this does leak... If you are using a recent compiler, you could use smart pointers to take care of this problem, although I do not recommend it if you are learning, it is important to understand memory management well.

For this particular case, the function should return a pointer, yes. Alternatively it could return a copy of the object by calling the copy constructor in the return statement and use a temporary in the body, but it is not a very clean solution.